# CSS Arrow on Select Doesn't Click

Tags: html, css, html-select

I have a select drop down with a CSS arrow (and line). If you click anywhere other than the arrow, the drop down opens, but not if you click directly on the arrow. I would like the arrow to be clickable as well.

Here's my code:

```css
.select {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.select:before,
.select:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.select:before {
  right: 37px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 1px;
  height: 22px;
  margin-top: -11px;
  background-color: #636667;
}

.select:after {
  right: 15px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: -3px;
  border: transparent 6px solid;
  border-top: #636667 6px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="select">
  <select class="form-control" id="state-dropdown">
 <option>Select State</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: can you turn this into a code snippet or a jsfiddle so we can see it? It doesn't display properly for me, it seems like something might be missing

Comment: Same here, I copied all of your code into a jsFiddle and not getting something that matches the question.  Fiddle in question: https://jsfiddle.net/3jkane8x/

Answer (score 8):

Try to add `pointer-events: none`.

Comment: So simple! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not working is because the pseudo elements are part of the parent wrapper, but even so, **pseudo elements don't work on select elements** at all anyway.

The easiest way around this is to use the following CSS to mimic the appearance through the `background` attribute instead.

*For example...*

```
select {
    background: url('image.png') 0px 0px no-repeat #fff;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

This question provides [a working example](http://%20%20%20%20%20-webkit-appearance:%20none;). Here is a link to [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pht9d295/3/) also included in that answer. **Credit is due to the answerer of that question for their working example.**

Comment: Thanks for this helpful explanation! I will try to use that approach in the future, but for now adding pointer-events: none worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style>
  .select {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

select {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance:    none;
   appearance:         none;
}

select {
 border: 0 none;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}


.select:before,
.select:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.select:before {
  right: 37px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 1px;
  height: 22px;
  margin-top: -11px;
  background-color: #636667;
}

.select:after {
  right: 15px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: -3px;
  border: transparent 6px solid;
  border-top: #636667 6px solid;
}

.select {
   border: 1px solid #666;
    border-radius: 0;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
 
 <div class="select">
  <select class="form-control" id="state-dropdown">
 <option>Select State</option>
  </select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```